# Show Camera image preview after click picture

Tags: android, camera, whatsapp

I am making a custom camera like whats app. When i open the custom camera it show me screen same as wats app.

[image]

When i click the image, I need to show the preview like whats app in given below image.i does not know what mechanism WHATS App use to show the preview

[image]

*Note - Does whats app use a image view to set the bit map for showing picture preview or some other sophisticated way.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you a working idea what WhatsApp doing in background in capture.

**Result of answer, Change layout design as preferred, my design is basic.**

[image]

**camera_preview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Add a caption...."
        android:textColorHint="#999999"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Okay"
            android:id="@+id/okay"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and `class` **Preview.java** as

```
public class Preview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_preview);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Intent data=getIntent();

        File imgFile = new File(data.getStringExtra("path"));
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenWidth = size.x;
        int screenHeight = size.y;

        // Get target image size
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

        // Scale the image down to fit perfectly into the screen
        // The value must be adjusted for phone/tables displays
        while (bitmapHeight > (screenHeight ) && bitmapWidth > (screenWidth)) {
            bitmapHeight = bitmapHeight / 2;
            bitmapWidth = bitmapWidth / 2;
        }

        // Create resized bitmap image
        BitmapDrawable resizedBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight,
                        false));


        image.setImageDrawable(resizedBitmap);
    }

    public void onCancelClick(View v){

    }

    public void onOkayClick(View v){

    }
```

From your main activity `startCamera` by

```
public void startCamera(){
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }
```

declare `String path` as global veriable

Inside `onCreate` method

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/example.jpg";
```

> I am starting activity for result Instead of startring activity you
>   can just shows a dialog,

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Intent startPreview = new Intent(this, Preview.class);
            startPreview.putExtra("path", path);
            startActivity(startPreview);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: I dont think whats app is doing same as you explained above.

Comment: yes you write, whats app create custom camera then create custom layout for result then display image, if you didn't understand, i will post code.

Comment: please post code. I will be very happy. I am excited to see. The main issue is i don't want to see any stretch in preview image .

Comment: did my answer solved your problem??if yes, then please accept and upvote , it will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Soory this is not perfect. not same as wats app do,

Comment: This code is not same as i mentioned in the beginning of answer, developer can understand what to do next after getting idea or logic.